# Merging multiple TIF files in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to combine multiple `.tif` files into one, but after merging, the new `.tif` file's image quality is very low.

How to increase that quality?

I want the new merged file quality as original quality. I am using this code to merged the tif file

```
   string[] sa = path;
        ImageCodecInfo info = null;
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo ice in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders())
            if (ice.MimeType == "image/tiff")
                info = ice;
        Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
        EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
        ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
        Bitmap pages = null;
        int frame = 0;
        foreach (string s in sa)
        {
            //  using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(s, FileMode.Open))
            {
                if (frame == 0)
                {
                    pages = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
                    //save the first frame
                    pages.Save(filepath, info, ep);
                }
                else
                {
                    //save the intermediate frames
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(s);
                    pages.SaveAdd(bm, ep);
                }
                if (frame == sa.Length - 1)
                {
                    //flush and close.
                    ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                    pages.SaveAdd(ep);
                }
                frame++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about this one, but I believe Multi-Frame TIFFs are encoded using G3 by default. Just giving something to try, change this:

```
Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(1);
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
```

to this:

```
Encoder enc = Encoder.SaveFlag;
Encoder encComp = Encoder.Encoder.Compression;
EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters(2);
ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(enc, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
ep.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(encComp, (long)EncoderValue.CompressionLZW);
```

And try again (you could also use `CompressionNone` instead of `CompressionLZW`, but LZW is lossless so it should not reduce the quality)